# Seeking in ad using Google ima sdk and videojs

Tags: javascript, video.js, vast, google-ima, vpaid

I currently cannot find a way to seek through ads using the videojs player and the ima sdk plugin for it. The [api documentation](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/v3/apis) doesent mention anything about seeking and using the seek function provided by videojs just seeks within the underlying content video, not within the actual ad.

It doesent seem to be a problem in other popular solutions like videojs + [MailOnline Plugin](https://github.com/MailOnline/videojs-vast-vpaid).

Is this actually not possible with the ima sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think that the SDK exposes a seek function as it is an uncommon case. Normally, ad vendors would not want their ads to be skipped to the end.